# How to reproduce infrequent 404?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, http-status-code-404

I have an app in Windows Phone Marketplace which sends Server (Tomcat, Java, Spring) data via POST call. I have added option in app to email developer in case an error occurs. I have received error emails from some users(20/300) and it shows http client is returning 404 against POST request. I have got no clue why some users are getting 404 while its working for rest of the users. If I turn my test mobile's Wifi and Cellular Connection off and run my app then I am able to reproduce exact same problem which users are facing. But when I ask them about internet connection, they claim its working.

My question is how can I try to debug and reproduce this issue? Any pointers..?

Comment: look into your DNS.. or try hard coding the IP address into the app, see how it goes. I suspect DNS resolution is the issue based on users location.

Comment: Are you able to get the web server logs? The 404 requests should be logged in there.

Comment: @DavidG I see some 404s in the log but they are all GET requests nothing POST

Comment: @HarisHasan One thing I've noticed about mobile networks is that the network operators often interfere with HTTP requests. In the past I've had to change the port that my APIs run on to bypass the pesky hidden proxy servers the operators insist on using.

Comment: When I make requests to our API (hosted on Azure) from my Nexus devices, sometimes I get weird DNS resolution errors. As soon as I hard code in the IP addy, all works as expected... it's bizarre to say the least (even happens when my device is on WiFi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chase Florell pointed at right direction. When users changed the network, app worked fine.